# Trying to copy entire structure to another structure of same type...but getting errors

Tags: c

Hi friends i am trying to copy a entire structure to another structure. When i compile, i don't get errors....when i print displays some garbage value....please guide me...Thanks!

In two different functions i am trying to add values and print it. My first function is "read_list"...in this i am getting the name of the student and marks inserted from the user.

My second functions is "print_list", using this function i am printing the details of student.

Please guide me to a tutorials where i can find few quite interesting examples using structure's in C

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct _student
{
    char name[50];
    unsigned int mark;
} student;

void print_list(student list[], int size);
void read_list(student list[], int size);

int main(void)
{  
    const int size = 3;

    student list_first[size];   //first structre
    student list_second[size];  //second structre of same type

    read_list(list_first, size); //list_first structer fills with values 
    print_list(list_first, size);  //to check i have printed it here 

    //Now as i knew that my first struct is filled with data .....so now i wanted to copy it 

    list_second[size] = list_first[size];               //cpoid from one struct to another
    printf("Second list is copied from another struct: \n");
    print_list(list_second, size);     //Tried to print it here ....

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}


void read_list(student list[], int size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    printf("Please enter the info:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("\nname: ");
        scanf("%s",&list[i].name);

        printf("\nMark: ");
        scanf("%d",&list[i].mark);
    }     
}

void print_list(student list[], int size)
{    
    unsigned int i;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\t %d\n",list[i].name,list[i].mark);
    }
}
```

Comment: memcpy (list_second, list_first, sizeof(student) * size);

Answer (score 3):

Use `memcpy()` to copy the arrays:

```
memcpy(list_second, list_first, sizeof(list_first));
```

The current assignment attempt is incorrect as it is accessing beyond the bounds of the array (arrays have zero based indexes, so valid indexes run from `0` to `size - 1`) causing undefined behaviour:

```
list_second[size] = list_first[size];
```

Even if it was not, it would only copy one of the elements and is the reason garbage is printed because `list_second` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_second[size] = = list_first[size];
```

is undefined behaviour as the allowed indices to `list_second` and `list_first` are `0` to `size - 1`. So using `size` as index you try to address the array element behind the last element.

To copy all array members use:

```
for (size_t sizeCnt = 0; sizeCnt < size, ++ sizeCnt)
{
  list_second[sizeCnt] = list_first[sizeCnt]; 
}
```

As a note: To access array elements, as well as to address memory the preferred integer type is `size_t`, which is defined to be an `unsigned` type to be wide enough to access the platforms address space.

Answer (score 0):

change `list_second[size] = list_first[size];` to `memcpy(list_second,list_first,sizeof(list_first));` you need to copy an array of structure, not a element. also `array[3]` means an array of 3 elements. So 2 is the maximum index allowed. `array[3]` is invalid